# PHP Security - (int) vs FILTER_VALIDATE_INT

Tags: php, variables, input, filter

I recently was told there is FILTER_VALIDATE_INT which is great by the way.

My question is in terms of taking an integer value from the website whether it maybe from user or generated from the web application, and passed via query string.

The value (integer) may be displayed or used in mysql query.

I am trying to structure the best possible security method for this.

With that in mind, is it safe to simply use

```
$myNum = (int)$_GET['num'];
```

Or

```
if (filter_var($_GET['num'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) $myNum = $_GET['num'];
```

Also, please explain what is the difference between using `(int)` and `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`

Comment: To expand on the existing answers, `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` is equivalent to `(int)` casting.

Comment: @mario, how can you say that? It is not.

Comment: Here is a fun note, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT says '0011' is not an int but '1111' is an int. The more you know...

Comment: Well (int) is a conversion while filer_var is validation

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The difference is that a cast to `int` will always get you an `int`, which may or may not be the original value. E.g. `(int)'foobar'` results in the `int` `0`. This makes it safe for most SQL purposes, but has nothing to do with the original value, and you won't even know it.

[`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` *tells* you whether the value is an `int`, based on which you can make the decision to use it in an SQL query or display an error message to the user.

Comment: @deceze would you happen to know if there is much of a difference between `filter_var` and its `is_int` counterpart?

Comment: @Russell Dias: results for `'42'` at least (integer represented as string).

Comment: @zerkms Oops didn't realize it tests a numeric string too. Thanks for the example ;)

Comment: Got it. It makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: @deceze It appears that FILTER_VALIDATE_INT also works with strings submitted from forms, so it works a little bit differently than you described.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge Yes, of course it operates on strings, that's the entire point. If I had an actual `int` I'd test it with `is_int()` and would be sure about the kinds of values it can contain.

Comment: @deceze You are wise and now you have proven it, too! ;-)

Comment: its worth the notice that `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` produces unexpected results for floating point numbers eg `3.0` and booleans eg `true`. [TEST](https://www.3v4l.org/5JQdU)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="text" name="param"></input>


$price = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'param', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if ($price !== false) {
print " a number.";    //works when value is number
}


if(is_int($_POST['param'])){
    print "is number."; //don't works when value is number
}
```

Please try test with when value is number  .