# What is the difference between filter_var(FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) and is_int?

Tags: php, random

I've used either function for checking and validating integers in many applications like so

$foo = $bar;

```
if (filter_var($foo,FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
// do something
}
```

AND

```
if (is_int($foo)) {
 // do something
}
```

Both works perfectly but I want to know the difference between the two in terms of speed and results because PHP being a tricky language has differences between functions that seem to do the same thing e.g [mt_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) and [rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)

Comment: Relevant from deceze also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4789649/2943403

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `filter` functions are designed to work on user input, which is always a string. `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` will validate whether *a string* is a valid integer (or it's already an `int`) and return an `int` if so.

`is_int` just tells you whether the type of a value is `int`.

Comment: It's also easy to mix up what `is_int()` and `is_numeric()` do. `filter_var($, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)` behaves more like `is_numeric($v) ? (int)$v : false`.